# Why is $y=\frac{x+y}{x}$ the same as $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$?

Tags: rational-functions

Why is $y=\frac{x+y}{x}$  the same as $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$?

It seems to be the same on graphing calculators, but I don't get why.
To generalize my statement, I would like to know how to simplify equations where "$y$" is on both sides, but can't be removed through conventional methods.

Comment: Not following.  One side depends on $y$ and the other does not, so they are not the same.

Comment: Ah, the header question is not the same as the actual question.  Confusing.

Comment: They *aren't* the same at x = 0, x = 1, and y=0.  But they are the same everywhere else by simply algebra.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, but $y$ *can* be removed through conventional methods in this case.  We have
$$y=\frac{x+y}{x}$$
$$xy = x + y$$
$$xy - y = x$$
$$(x-1)y = x$$
$$y = \frac{x}{x-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, i can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @John After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Assuming x-1 ne 0 and x ne 0.  That is one difference.  The second is undefined at x = 1  but defined at x = 0 (y = 0). The first has y undefined at x = 0 and has the impossible statement y = y + 1 at x = 1.  At all other values they are the same. Likewise at y= 0 the second is fine (x = 0) but and y = 0 in the first you have the unsolvable 0 = x/x.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question, they are not the same.

The first one is an implicit expression in $y$. It makes no sense for $x=0$. The second one is explicit in $y$, and it is defined for $x=0$. So the graphs are indeed different, since they differ at least in one point.

Yet for many other $x$, their graphs coincide.

A simpler and similar example is $f_1(x) =\frac{x}{x}$ and $f_2 (x)=1$. Almost the same, except for one little detail at $0$.

Your second question is a bit broad. When $y$ is on both sides, there are several methods, depending on how things are involved: variable re-parametrisation, equation solving, higher dimension embedding...

Comment: As well as x = 0 making no sense y= 0 makes no sense for the first (0 = x/x).  The first is makes no sense at x = 1 (y = y+1) and the second makes sense but is undefined.  (y = 1/0).  At all other x or all other y both equations are solvable and equivalent.